# Adding a new DB service to CloudFoundry

Tags: cassandra, cloud-foundry

I would like to add Cassandra to CloudFoundry.  How can that be achieved?  I was looking at the information posted here: [CouchDB in CloudFoundry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458058/couchdb-in-cloudfoundry) but that is using the included CouchDB.

I also have been combing through this wiki https://github.com/cloudfoundry/oss-docs/tree/master/vcap/adding_a_system_service, but that doesn't give me enough information on how to point to my externally hosted Cassandra service.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify your question with regard to what you're trying to achieve? Are you a) trying to add Cassandra to the list of available supported services (that anyone would get if they took your CF distro) or b) trying to add YOUR cassandra to YOUR -behind the firewall- install of CF?  If the former, you can also have a look at http://programminggems.wordpress.com/2012/03/12/adding-gemstone-as-a-service-to-cloud-foundry/ which uses Gemstone as an example. But maybe you're referring to the latter?

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to the latter.  We have a private cloud running CloudFoundry and what to add our instance of Cassandra to it.

Answer (score 4):

Although there's not much information on it, the Service Broker tool will let you expose an external service to a VCAP deployment (so that the service is displayed when running `vmc services`).

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap-services/tree/master/service_broker

There isn't a how-to or other docs to speak of, so your best bet is to read the source and post questions on the vcap-dev google group. Here's an existing thread on Service Broker:

https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/d/topic/vcap-dev/sXF9rWzMMHc/discussion

Comment: I tried to use the ".../bin/service_broker_cli -c my-config-file -v" command, and the content of my-config-file.yml is shown as below: service_broker: http://service_broker.vcap.me
     token: "changecassandratoken"
     service:
        name:cassandra-broker
        description:Cassandra Service
        version: "1.0.10"
        options:
          - name: cassandra
            acls:
                users: []
                wildcards: []
            credentials:
                conn: cassandra://cassbx01.qualcomm.com:9160/foursq  I get this error: no such file to load

Answer (score 1):

If you want to connect directly your existing services from your private cloud, I then see 2 solutions :

- Do nothing special and have your code connect to those services, assuming they are visible from the network and no firewall sits between them. Of course, you'll want to make their address configurable, but other than that, it is as if you were hitting a third party
- create some kind of "gateway" service whose role would be to proxy the connection to your private service

Of course, a third solution would be to have a real "CloudFoundry" oriented Cassandra service, and migrate your existing data to it (but then it would not be accessible from the rest of your IS, unless you create a bridge the other way around)

I would start with option 1) and depending on your processes and usage, research solution 2) afterwards.