# CouchDB in CloudFoundry - Part 2: User Add Failure

Tags: couchdb, cloud-foundry

Per this post [CouchDB in CloudFoundry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458058/couchdb-in-cloudfoundry), I tried the same thing, but when I run `vmc create-service couchdb` I get the following error reported in the couchdb_node.log:

```
[2012-10-01 11:31:47.335301] couchdb_node_0 - pid=22864 tid=dfcc fid=c5c1   INFO -- Creating credentials: ue26fa08a-e8d1-4043-8ba4-71f7d779ce08/pa1cdc5d8-2e92-41ef-b2f1-bdb61b8ce693 for database d73a7c8d1-9b5e-411c-ab92-09f96c7875c2
[2012-10-01 11:31:47.338018] couchdb_node_0 - pid=22864 tid=dfcc fid=c5c1  ERROR -- Failed add user ue26fa08a-e8d1-4043-8ba4-71f7d779ce08: 401 Unauthorized
[2012-10-01 11:31:47.342074] couchdb_node_0 - pid=22864 tid=dfcc fid=c5c1   INFO -- Deleting user ue26fa08a-e8d1-4043-8ba4-71f7d779ce08
[2012-10-01 11:31:47.344598] couchdb_node_0 - pid=22864 tid=dfcc fid=c5c1  ERROR -- Failure deleting user ue26fa08a-e8d1-4043-8ba4-71f7d779ce08: 401 Unauthorized
[2012-10-01 11:31:47.349463] couchdb_node_0 - pid=22864 tid=dfcc fid=c5c1   WARN -- Exception at on_provision 401 Unauthorized: {"error":"unauthorized","reason":"Name or password is incorrect."}\n
```

On the client side it reports an Error 503. What do I need to do that would allow me to add users? I run CF as root on Linux Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 1):

It was an issue where another version of CouchDB was running in the background.  After killing that, I got past this error.